How to add Postgres FK constraints to a DB that already has orphaned data?
I'm faced with a client's DB that never had FK constraints added. As such, there's lots of orphaned items.
I'm trying to add the constraints now, after the fact, via ALTER TABLE..., but the orphans are causing errors along the lines of

ERROR: insert or update on table "" voilates foreign key constraint ...

I understand why that's happening. But how can I add these constraints, without first manually going through each table and finding then removing orhpans, which is infeasible? It's acceptable for the constraints to take effect only for future inserts, and for the existing orphans to remain in place.
I've read about DEFERRABLE and INITIALLY DEFERRED/IMMEDAITE and came up with this, but I'm getting the same error.
ALTER TABLE foo
ADD FOREIGN KEY (bar_id)
REFERENCES bar (id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;

Probably I'm going about this wrongly (I'm no Postgres wizard). What's the best way here?

Also note that DEFERRABLE has nothing to do with the existing data, it's only about when the constraint is checked for inserts/updates.

That does indeed answer my question, and so this is a dup. Thank you.
